# Reducing number of lines of code in test class (Builder - Factory pattern)

Tags: java, integration-testing, builder, factory-pattern

I am writing integration test class which has a lots of test cases (50+). I have to create multiple objects of different types in each test method. Because of large number of test methods and multiple object creation in each test my test class is becoming very bulky. I need suggestions regarding how can I make it less verbose and understandable.

What I have done so far - Objects that I need to create are complex. For example Object A has Object B which has a list of Object C which has a field - Value. I need to create an instance of Object A with value 5. So I moved all this code to another class and called it ABuilder with Method - buildWithValue(). Now in the test class I simply do Abuilder.buildWithValue(5). This took away some code from main test class.

But now I have multiple such builders BBuilder, CBuilder. Shall I move all of these builders to a abstract builder or something ? Something like GenericBuilder which takes as input Builder type and other parameters to build an object and even if I do so, number of lines won't get reduced much.

So, can I do this - Create a generic builder with a method which accepts three values (different data types) - value1, value2, value3 which are required by my ABuilder, BBuilder and CBuilder. Doing it this way my test method will just have one line GenericBuild.createObjects(A1,B1,C1)

Or shall I split the test class into two based on some criteria ?

Please suggest

Comment: Why don't you just create a function in the class which creates a class A object. Creating a class ,which has only testing purpose ,is not a good approach in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the builder pattern, I'd allow for the construction and persisting of your nested objects as JSON, XML or any format that's both human and machine readable.  You can easily create new objects in a text editor, place the text files in your /src/test/resources folder (for example, if you're using maven) and construct them as needed in your test cases.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean when you say - You can easily create new objects in a text editor, place the text files in your /src/test/resources folder.  May be a small example

Comment: Personally, I find Java code more readable (not to mention more flexible, powerful, type safe, and performant) than JSON or XML, for this purpose; just design a nice set of helper classes/methods for data creation and use them in your tests.

Comment: @Rogério That was my point.  The JSON just makes for easier editing of the data